# Finding the residue of a function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z) = \frac{ e^z - 1}{\sin z }$. Im trying to find $Res(f,z_0=0) $

I know that $(z-0)f(z)= \frac{ z(e^z-1)}{\sin z }$. And the limit as $z \to 0$ is of the form $0/0$ so applying lhopitals rule, we get that the limit is actually $0$. Can we conclude that the residue is then $0$ ?

In my notes, it says that the limit $\lim_{z \to z_0} (z-z_0) f(z) $ must be nonzero and then it equals the residue. Is there other ways to find the residue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$z=0$ is a pole of order $0$ (it mean it a false singularity). Then $res(f,0)=0$. Indeed
$$f(z)=\frac{z}{\sin(z)}\frac{e^z-1}{z}\underset{z\to 0}{\longrightarrow }1$$
and thus $f$ is holomorphe on $0$ and thus the residu is $0$.

Comment: I thought for this work $p(z_0)$ cannot be $0$ ?

Comment: But, then, $z_0$ is not a simple pole, right?

Comment: But, the theorem in my books states: $f$ analytic on a region $A$ and $z_0$ isolated singularity. Then $z_0$ is a simple pole $\iff$ $\lim_{z \to z_0} (z-z_0)f(z) $ exists and is unequal to zero. This limit is the residue of $f$ at $z_0$.

Comment: Sorry to induced you in error, but in fact you can erase this singularity (it's a false singularity). So forget all what I did before. I edited my answer.

Comment: Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_%28complex_analysis%29): *"A few authors allow the order of a pole to be zero, in which case a pole of order zero is either a regular point or a removable singularity. However, it is more usual to require the order of a pole to be positive."*

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer your question "Are there other ways to find the residue?"

Its been a little while since I did complex calculus but I'm pretty sure if you find the Laurent Series then find the coefficient $a_{-1}$ then that is your residue.